# Onclick Event is not working on chrome and Explorer but working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, explorer

I am firing onclick event based on condition.But click event is working on Firefox but not working on Chrome and Explorer. Can you please help?
Below is Javascript code

```
function SaveOrCancelConfirmation(btnId) {
  if (confirm("Do you want to save the changes ")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    if (btnId == "imgShowNext")
      document.getElementById("ctlWorkingDaysCalender_btnHidden").click();
    else
      document.getElementById("ctlWorkingDaysCalender_btnHidden2").click();
  }
}
```

Here is the two button

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="HdnButton_Click" /> 
 <asp:Button ID="btnHidden2" runat="server" style="display:none;" OnClick="HdnButton2_Click" />
```

Here the Methods

```
protected void HdnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach(DataRow dr in _selectedDates.Tables[0].Select("IsDBData='0'"))
        {
            dr.Delete();
        }
        ViewState[VS_DATES] = _selectedDates;
        imgShowNext_Click(sender, null);
    }
    protected void HdnButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataRow dr in _selectedDates.Tables[0].Select("IsDBData='0'"))
        {
            dr.Delete();
        }
        ViewState[VS_DATES] = _selectedDates;
        imgShowPrevious_Click(sender, null);

    }
```

I am expecting that when it comes to else part then it should invoke respective method via onclick event in all browser,But it is not firing the click Event in Chrome and Explorer whereas it does fire in Firefox.

Comment: "but not working"... What is not working? There's errors in the console? what happen when you click? Please, describe the problem and the desired result.

Comment: use jsfiddle and make an example and then link to it so we can test it in different browsers.  Hard to help without all the code.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: the method I am trying to hit in else condition part is getting hit in chrome,but it get called in Firefox

Comment: @Moose here is the  code in JSFiddler <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/MojCoder/p81oztfs/1/embed/"></script> Could you please give any lead towards the solution